# Which is the object, 'one' or 'another' ? I just don't know how this sentence constructed

Tags: grammar, pronouns, objects

> (All the condoms are faulty. Abed need to notice everybody) 
>   Go, Abed, Go. before people sex one another!

Comment: This sounds like the weirdest reading primer I've ever heard. We're a long way from Dick and Jane and "Run, Spot, run!"

Comment: What's ' Dick and Jane' ?

Comment: @snooze: "Dick and Jane" refers to the title of an early reader book, one that most US native speakers probably used when learning how to read.

Comment: But at least half the title was appropriate ;)

Comment: @Kit, "most" US native speakers used it, provided that those native speakers are at least 50 years old. I don't think that Dick and Jane has actually been used in most schools since the 60s. However, it's entered the collective consciousness, so even people who have never actually read a Dick and Jane book (such as myself) know what it's about.

Comment: for enlightenment http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ww3gyDJTn2E&t=1m55s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The construction of that fragment is a little convoluted, so let's break it down:

```
(You) go before {people sex one another}.
```

The subject "you" is implied, as is normal with the imperative. I've indicated this with parentheses. The word *before* is a conjunction, and it introduces the clause *people sex one another*, which is in curly braces.

The clause *people sex one another* is a straightforward transitive clause using *sex* as a verb, which in this case means "to have sex with". The object of the verb is the reciprocal pronoun phrase *one another*, which indicates that the action is being performed mutually within a group of two or more people. (This is subtly different from the reflexive, which indicates that the subject acts on itself.)

Comment: I just don't know  reciprocal pronoun phrase and 'one another' is a phrase.

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard "sex" used as a verb before. Also, the sentence beginning with "before" is incomplete.

I would rephrase the entire post thusly:

(All the condoms are faulty. Abed *needs* to *notify* everybody.)
Go, Abed, go -- before people *have sex with one another*!

or

-- before *people start having sex!*

Comment: Google "sexing" sometime. Maybe not at work though.

Comment: It's not clear from the post, but this is actually a quotation from a clip.  mplungjan posts the link in the comments below the post.  In this case, it's an intentional misuse of language by someone who is supposed to be a non-native English speaker.

Answer (score 1):

> People sex one another.

Traditional grammar might analyse the clause as follows.

*People* = subject

*One another* = an elliptical parallel/parenthetical clause:

> People sex; one sexes another.
>
> People sex (one [sexes] another).

In this hypothetical elliptical clause, *one* would be subject and *another* object. This probably best reflects the origin of the phrase. JSBangs' very useful analysis, following modern linguistics, might be used by more traditional grammarians as well, because *one another* is a fixed, idiomatic phrase and the class of reflexive pronouns is well established as a suppletive class.

Comment: So, you don't think 'one another' is object. and People is subject and also object too ?

Comment: @snooze: No, I'd call *people* subject in any case. If you take *one another* as an elliptical clause, *one* is subject and *another* object in the hypothetical clause *one sexes another*. // If you take the whole phrase *one another* as a reflexive pronoun, it is object.